# Java - storage structure for the preferences?

Tags: java, data-structures

What i need to do, is to store a preference stucture in an object.
Is there a usual pattern how to save the properties in Java, with the following preconditions:

- different Datatypes are can be displayed as settings (Boolean, Int, Checkbox)
- different DataTypes have different number of values (Boolean has one, checkbox has many)
- it is not known how many preference entries there will exist.

  ```
          {TYPE;NAME;VALUE} 
          {TYPE;NAME;VALUE} 
          {TYPE;NAME;VALUE}
  ```

For Example:

```
            {CHECKBOXES;"Radio box choice"; { Red, White, Blue}}
            {BOOLEAN;"Hintergrund"; true}} 
            {INT;"Page number"; 34}} 
            {STRING;"App title";"Jenny"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base JavaBean (POJO) called Preference with the properties *type*, *name* and *values*. Create subclasses of Preference for each preference type, such as CheckboxPref, BooleanPref, etc. Override behavior appropriately in these subclasses. For instance setValue() in CheckBoxPref might have a different behavior than setValue() in IntPref.

Then create another class called PreferenceManager. Store a Collection of Preference there, and expose methods such as loadPreferences(File preferenceFile), setPreferenceValue(String name).

PreferenceManager could also be used as a FactoryMethod for creating the right Preference subclass, according to the Preference Type.

Not sure if that's a Pattern, but that's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the Java Preferences API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to represent a property. and use a List in your object.

```
class Property{

   enum dataType; //create a specific enum
   String name;
   Object value;

}
```

If you want to go further then you could inherit from this property to add somme type specialised class like BooleanProperty or StringProperty.